# Strange for loop behavior in Javascript function 

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I have this below loop in my function

I see it loop through if x is <10 but if it is greater than 10 it fails even though the condition of y < x satisfies

```
function insert(x,y) {

   for (var shift = y; shift < x; shift++) {
      //get into loop for insert (9,2) but not for insert(10,2) 
   }       

}
```

This is the actual function, I am trying to visualize a insert before scenario using rapheal.js it works for insertBeforeTo(9,2) but when i try insertBeforeTo(10,2)  it do not get into the loop.

```
function insertBeforeTo(whichElementI, insertBeforeI) {

     var twhichElement = blocks[whichElementI];
     blocks[whichElementI].animate({ x: blocks[insertBeforeI].attr('x') }, 1000, ">");
     var shiftplusone = insertBeforeI;
     for (var shift = insertBeforeI; shift < whichElementI; shift++) {

         ++shiftplusone;
         blocks[shift].animate({ x: blocks[shiftplusone].attr('x') }, 1000, ">");// check  value actually changes

     }
}
```

Down voters: mind explaining?

Issue found: while debugging I see whichElementI and insertBeforeI values in ' '. So I assume It takes it as a string and as nnnnn and paxdiablo rightly pointed out, it takes as string instead of int so It worked for whichElementI = 9 and insertBeforeI =  2 and not whichElementI= 10 ,insertBeforeI=2.

So I used unary plus operator like +whichElementI, +insertBeforeI which fixes the issue.

Thanks

Comment: What exactly happens when you enter 10,2 as the arguments? Does it not execute at all?

Comment: Post some more code please? Try a console.log(shift); to see what is going on inside the loop.

Comment: Works fine in both cases for me: http://jsfiddle.net/rxDXG/2/

Comment: yes it do not gets into   the loop

Comment: I cant reproduce the problem either.

Comment: Seems to work for me. http://jsfiddle.net/33sYj/

Comment: And what _types_ are `x` and `y` - it looks like it might be using lexicographical ordering (strings rather than numbers) where `"10"` is indeed less than `"2"`.

Comment: Quick way to make sure the types are numeric, put x=x*1;y=y*1; as the first line.

Comment: Note about SO code formatting: if you indent each line with four spaces SO will format it as code. Or if typing or pasting unindented code, select it and click the `{}` button and SO will indent it for you (don't use the block-quoting with `>` for code). If you want to put a piece of code inline in a sentence like `function()` then quote it with the ` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you are inadvertantly calling your function with string values rather than number values, that is with

```
insert("9", "2")
insert("10", "2")
```

...rather than

```
insert(9, 2)
insert(10, 2)
```

If you are getting your values from html element attributes, for example, they'll be strings.

With *strings*, `"2" < "9"` is `true`, but `"2" < "10"` is `false` - it does a lexicographic (dictionary) order comparison, not a numeric comparison.

If you want your function to work either way then you can change it to convert strings to numbers (I prefer to use the [unary plus operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29) for that purpose):

```
function insert(x,y) {

   x = +x;
   y = +y;

   for (var shift = y; shift < x; shift++) {
      //get into loop for insert (9,2) but not for insert(10,2) 
   }       

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should first check what data types you're passing in to the function.

For example, all of these produce output:

```
insert ( 10,   2)
insert (  9,   2)
insert ( '9', '2')
```

but the following does *not:*

```
insert ( '10', '2')
```

That's because the *string* `'10'` is actually less than the string `'2'`. By that, I mean that a string is not treated numerically when sorting or comparing, rather each *character* is compared individually, leading to things like the first twelve numbers being sequenced as:

```
1
10
11
12
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

You can see this in action with the following code (at [one of the many on-line JS runners](http://writecodeonline.com/javascript/)):

```
function insert(x,y) {
   for (var shift = y; shift < x; shift++) {
      //get into loop for insert (9,2) but not for insert(10,2) 
      document.write('x');
   }       
}
document.write('<br>10,2 as string: '); insert ('10','2');
document.write('<br>9,2 as string: ');  insert ( '9','2');
document.write('<br>9,2 as num: ');     insert (  9,  2);
document.write('<br>10,2 as num: ');    insert ( 10,  2);
```

which outputs:

```
10,2 as string: 
9,2 as string: xxxxxxx
9,2 as num: xxxxxxx
10,2 as num: xxxxxxxx
```

If you have a string that you want treated as a number, [`parseInt()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) is one way to go, something like:

```
var str42 = '42';
var num42 = parseInt (str42, 10);
```

Comment: can you please elaborate I sort of guessed this when I debug it tells '9' and '10' so i guess i have to cast it right.. I still do not get how 9 works and not 10

Comment: Ajax3.14 - strings are compared character by character, so `'10'` comes before `'2'` for the same reason that "aa" comes before "b" if you're alphabetising your bookshelf... @FlavorScape: `parseInt()` is almost always the worst choice for converting a string to a number, unless you specifically want strings with non-numeric characters at the end to work (e.g., `parseInt('12abc')` returns `12`).

Comment: @FlavorScape yeah got it... nnnnnn recommended unary plus operator and it worked...

Comment: parseInt is fine for converting strings to numbers unless you specifically want to _catch_ errors like `12abc`. That's subtly different to what you stated, nnnnnn. Multiplying `42abc` by `-1` will get you `NaN` - whether that's suitable is a level above where this question is at.

Comment: I view it the other way around: I want a conversion method that I know will fail for _any_ non-numeric data, because if I'm expecting a number then `"12abc"` is an error. I don't want one that will "work" on `"12abc"` but fail on `"abc12"`. Having said that, if the data is coming from a source I don't control I would explicitly validate it. I _would_ happily use `parseInt()` as a shortcut when dealing with data that will legitimately have digits followed by non-digits, e.g., CSS measurements like `"12px"`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what the types of whichElementI and insertBeforeI are, but convert them to numeric by *1. That should help keep some of the arithmetic in check. Might also want to check if(isNaN(some_var)==false){...} as a sanity check.

```
function insertBeforeTo(whichElementI, insertBeforeI) {

 var twhichElement = blocks[whichElementI];
 blocks[whichElementI].animate({ x: blocks[insertBeforeI].attr('x') }, 1000, ">");
 var shiftplusone = insertBeforeI*1;
 for (var shift = insertBeforeI*1; shift < whichElementI*1; shift++) {
    ++shiftplusone;
    blocks[shift].animate({ x: blocks[shiftplusone].attr('x') }, 1000, ">");// check x value  actually changes

  }
}
```

Comment: The Javascript function Numeric(some_var) will also attempt to convert to type numeric